# Can't query from django where field name has double underscore

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Can't query from django where field name has double underscore.
This is because in the django query language `__` has its own meaning

so how can I query a field whose actual name is `"my__fyeild__name"` ?

```
template.fields.filter(my__fyeild__name="aaa")
```

In the database the column has a name with two underscores `__`, and I am not allowed to rename that column.

Comment: Why do you define a field name with double underscores in the first place? To the best of my knowledge, you can not query with fields with double underscores, since Django will first split these by the `__` part.

Comment: the worst remark to a "how do I do X?" question in SO is "why do you want to do X"?.   But if you have to know, I am working on a DB table that was created by someone else with field names that have "__".

Comment: no it is not, since Django can perfectly deal with fields that have a different name than the name in Django, so this is the famous XY problem :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: In fact it is a very common phenomena that if a person asks "How to do Y", that the answer is "you should not do Y in the first place, you can fix the original problem in a better way". This is exactly why asking "why do you want to do Y?" is useful since it can sometimes be solved in a better way.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, since Django will always split on the `__` part. But I think you do not need this anyway. You can define a field at the Django level, that has a different name on the database level.

We can define a model for example with a field where we specify the name of the column at the database level with the [**`db_column=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    my_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_column='my__field__name')
```

So here you can query on `my_field_name`, and Django will automatically use the `my__field__name` in the query.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why should we put a ***double underscore*** in the model field. The Django uses the double underscore notation for lookup purpose.

[From the doc of **Field name restrictions**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#field-name-restrictions)

> A field name cannot contain more than one underscore in a row, due to the way Django’s query lookup syntax works. For example:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    foo__bar = models.IntegerField() # 'foo__bar' has two underscores!
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer:** I am being sarcastic when I say this is a "solution".  This is a **terrible idea** and, in my opinion, should never be implemented.  I am only showing this to add clarity to *why* you can't add `__` to model columns, in hope that you will reconsider the problem at hand.

As a response to the answers saying that you *can't* have double underscore field names:

**yes you can**!

It's easy, just go to `django/db/models/constants.py` and change the `LOOKUP_SEP` to whatever you want (for this example I will use `_some_new_sep_`)

Here are some examples:

myapp/models:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    test__col = models.IntegerField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bar', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

usage:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Foo, Bar
>>> Foo.objects.create(test__col=1)
<Foo: Foo object (1)>
>>> Bar.objects.create(foo_id=1, title='test')
<Bar: Bar object (1)>
>>>
>>> Foo.objects.filter(bar_some_new_sep_title='test')
<QuerySet [<Foo: Foo object (1)>]>
```

There is only one **small downside**, it will cause any third party applications  that hard code the default `LOOKUP_SEP` to **break**.  As it turns out, this is pretty much *every* app that uses it (including the default django apps).

As WilliamVanOsem stated in the comments:

> In fact it is a very common phenomena that if a person asks "How to do Y", that the answer is "you should not do Y in the first place, you can fix the original problem in a better way".

Comment: I would be a bit careful with claiming this, since it is not part of the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/search/?q=LOOKUP_SEP). Technically one can indeed do that, but since it is not documented, the implementers can easily change their mind, and I'm not sure that all Django tooling works with this constant. +1 anway :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for your comment.  I added a disclaimer at the top of my answer so no one is mislead into thinking this is a *good* idea.

Comment: Since `LOOKUP_SEP` is not documented, it should probably not be changed.

Comment: I like this answer for being technically correct, but still a terrible idea.